# One iPhone app with different template based on the URL it was downloaded from

Tags: iphone, distribution, tracking

I want to give my iPhone app to different distributors for distribution.

When a user will download the app from one of the distributors and open it the app should connect to our servers and ask for the unique settings of this distributer.

The question is, how each app can "tell" from which distributer it was downloaded from?

I don't want to compile a different application for each client.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research into this and the only way I found to do it is just to create different targets for each app then share the source code across both the apps, but this still means that you would have to do two submissions still.

Comment: you mean a submission per distributer?

Comment: Yeah, its a pain but it is the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an app or iOS WebApp?
if you want iOS app, I do not think you can distribute to other distributors, because Apple is the only distributor of iOS applications, so all the downloads come from there.

if you want a WebApp, you create a download link redirected to your webapp to read the link to the server it pulls everything you need, layout, information, etc ...

Comment: I want iOS app.
When I said distributer - someone that advertise my app.
That way, each advertiser can advertise the same app but with different looks/features.

Comment: If you advertise in the app, you can use JSON to fetch the features according to the announcement that is displayed, it is easy to do.

If the advertiser, with your app on any site and when the customer clicks, redirects to AppStore, there just creating different apps even.

Or another option is to create a WebApp, which is an app "Safari" connecting to a site and everything would work as a site but within that app. This way you can do a redirect for each advertiser in one app only.

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I want to submit only 1 app.

Comment: So you have to create a WebApp. Create a "mask" like this APP and APP open the UIWebView. For each distributor you use JSON to know where it came from the APP recommend and the UIWebView you connect with different features. Thus you have an app with different features. Got it?